# PHP - Echo new line character "\n" as single quote string

Tags: php, echo, newline, double-quotes, single-quotes

How can I echo the new line character \n as if it was in a single quote string?

```
$foo = 'foo';
$nl = getStringWithNewLineCharacter();
$bar = 'bar';

echo $foo . $nl . $bar;
```

will output :

```
foo
bar
```

What I want is :

```
foo\nbar
```

(Obviously, I do not control the return value of the getStringWithNewLineCharacter() function.)

Or said differently, how can I force a variable to be interpreted as a single quote string?

---

**EDIT**

While answers provided gave a workaround, the real question here is how to interpret a double quoted string variable as a single quoted string variable. Maybe it's not possible, I don't know. To answer this, it requires understanding of how the interpreter manages string variables (which I lack).

So :

- How is the "quote type" of a string defined?
- Is it immutable?
- Is there a way to change how the interpreter will manage a string variable?

Comment: And why is a singe quote string not an option. It seems the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: wouldnt it work to escape the `\n` by prepending `\ `  so it would be `\\n`

Comment: Are you saying that you dont want the `\n` to be a newline control character but instead just 2 chars of text

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Comment: Several people seem to have trouble reading the question, and are just telling you how to stop the `\n` being interpreted as a new line. That's not really the what was asked. The OP clearly already knows that.

Answer (score 2):

Not totally sure this is what you want but here goes anyway.

I think you are saying that you have no control over the returned value of `getStringWithNewLineCharacter();` and you think it is returning `"\n"` i.e. a newline control character sequence.

This would simply convert the `"\n"` to `'\n'`

```
<?php

$foo = 'foo';
$nl = "\n";
$bar = 'bar';

echo $foo . $nl . $bar;   // 2 lines
echo PHP_EOL;

$nl = str_replace("\n", '\n', $nl);
echo $foo . $nl . $bar;   // one line
echo PHP_EOL;
```

RESULTS:

```
foo
bar

foo\nbar
```

#### EDIT:

Or if you want to make it permanent at least for the duration of this script do :-

```
$nl = str_replace("\n", '\n',getStringWithNewLineCharacter());
```

Comment: Indeed this works, thanks. But it implies using str_replace every time which is quite tedious . Isn't there a simpler way like some casting-like operation?

Comment: See EDIT suggestion

Comment: The fact is I have hundreds of such variables in my scripts so a little casting-like trick with the echo or during the concatenation would be nice. How can I tell the interpreter to use a variable as a single quoted string rather than a double quoted one? But maybe it's not possible, idk.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the backslash, that neutralizes its behavior:

```
echo "foo\\nbar";
```

You can write that in a literal manner as above or in a string replacement command, whatever. The outcome is the same: the literal characters `\` and `n` next to each other instead of the line feed character:

```
echo $foo . str_replace("\n", "\\n", $nl) . $bar;
```

Or obviously:

```
echo $foo . str_replace("\n", '\n', $nl) . $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the ', not the "', like this  `echo '\n'` not `echo "\n"`

Comment: Thats the opposite of what the OP just asked!

Answer (score 0):

Once the "\n" character is in the variable, it's already converted to newline. You will need to convert it back.

```
$nl = preg_replace("#\n#", '\n', $nl);
```

Comment: Or to keep it simple `$nl = str_replace("\n", '\n', $nl);`

Comment: That's also good. I tend to default to RegEx. Something to do with my Perl origins :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $foo = 'foo';
    $nl = htmlspecialchars('\n');
    $bar = 'bar';

    echo $foo . $nl . $bar;
?>
```